# What are the advantages and disadvantages of a Darlington pair?

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-electronics, single-supply-op-amp, small-signal

Can the BJT transistors in a Darlington pair be of different types?What are the advantages and disadvantages of a Darlington pair? Is such a circuit able to generate
power by itself?

Comment: "*Is such a circuit able to generate power by itself?*" Can you explain why you asked this?

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage is you get a ton of current gain (round about the square of an individual transistor of the same type).

Yes, you could use two dissimilar transistors.

Main disadvantage is Vbe is effectively doubled to about 1.4V, and, just two transistors (though typically you get them in one package).

No, they cannot generate power "by themselves". It's a semiconductor, not an energy source.

Comment: The OPs question would be appear to be homework with zero effort made. This answer rewards their zero effort by handing over the answer, instead of guiding the OP's next steps so that they must solve it themselves and learn.

Answer (score 0):

- Advantage: Very high current gain allowing a pretty large input resistance.
- Disadvantage: The resulting transconductance which determines the voltage gain of a DARLINGTON stage is only 50% if compared with the capabilities of the second transistor and its own transonductance (this is the price to be paid for the large input resistance).
- Summary: The DARLINGTON combination (if compared with a single transistor) allows a higher input resistance in exchange with a smaller transconductance.
- Comment: Two different transistor types are not only allowed but it makes sense two use a combination of a small-signal transistor and a high-current (power) transistor.

Comment: The OPs question would be appear to be homework with zero effort made. This answer rewards their zero effort by handing over the answer, instead of guiding the OP's next steps so that they must solve it themselves and learn.

Comment: OK - I know what you mean. In principle, I share your position - on the other hand - in this specific case "solve it themselves...". According to my experience, it is not so easy to find answers to the basic questions (diffrerent types, advantages/disadvantages). For example - the "Art of Electronics" gives no answers (no formulas). Some other books show how to derive the describing formulas for DARLINGTON - but this alone does not yet answer the questions.

Comment: That's a productive, kind, generous and laudable attitude that is valued in engineering circles and also not earnt by every OP that visits these shores :-)